# DBT and BigQuery: NOT ENFORCED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt

I have a dbt model thats being materialised as a table.

```
-- models/my_model.sql

with my_model as (
  select
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
  from
    source_table
)

select
  column1,
  column2,
  column3
from
  my_model
```

I want it to use a "NOT ENFORCED" qualifier when a table is created. Something with this equivalent:

```
ALTER TABLE my_model 
ADD primary key(colmn1) NOT ENFORCED
```

The not enforced qualifier will help identify the primary key and will optimise queries when run.

How can I do that in DBT?

Im new to DBT and couldn't find any resources that talks about the PK creation.

Comment: Look at dbt constraints, try that out and report back what you tried and what didnt't work for you,

Comment: I used this and did a dbt_run full refresh
models:
  - name: my_model
    description: "table description"
    columns:
        - name: column1
          description: "column1 description"
          quote: true
          constraints:
            - type: not_null
            - type: primary_key
          tests:
            - not_null

When i checked the table in BigQuery, it doesn't have the "PK"  in the Key:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the post-hook to add the primary key constraint resolved the issue

Comment: Please could you develop a little bit more your answer?